# Text overlap when delete big text in Android edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

The text overlap when delete all big text within one line. Which is a rendering issue because all things back to normal when i scroll down then scroll back.

Already try trigger invalidate after text change but no luck.

Is there other method to force re-render?

[image]

[image]

**Update: Just a simple edittext, I am deleting "sdf" using IME.**

Comment: Let us have a look at the XML code.

Comment: post your xml file for better understanding.